# PHP_EOL and "\n" leave 1st line blank

Tags: php, blank-line

I have simple code that saves data:

```
$data = $_POST["data"];
$userID = $_POST["userID"]; 

if (empty($data)){
   } else {
    $theFile = fopen("Data/" . $userID . ".txt", "a+");
    fwrite($theFile, PHP_EOL.$data);
    fclose($theFile);      
}
```

Data works fine for saving the data, but there is *always* a blank line in line 1. I've tried switching to "\n" and the problem persists. Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: `$data.PHP_EOL`, so the EOL is appended after the data. That way, there is a line break after the last line, so the new data can be appended on the blank, empty line at the end of the file.

Comment: You've got a directory traversal vulnerability. A user could provide a userID like `../../../path/to/some/other/directory`. You'll want to validate that string before you use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change:

```
fwrite($theFile, PHP_EOL.$data);
```

With:

```
fwrite($theFile, $data.PHP_EOL);
```

Otherwise you'll have this first line empty as the first written char is a \n

Comment: That solved it. I have no idea you could switch the order. Thanks!!

Comment: @KalifVaughn What possible reason could there be why you couldn't change the order? It's just string concatenation, not a magic incantation. Just put things in the order that you want them.